# Write pseudocode of a program that prints such a pattern

Tags: loops, pseudocode

Analyze output pattern and write algorithm of a program that prints such a pattern.

**Input 4 

Pattern:**
55555 
4444 
333
22
1

**Input 3 

Pattern:**
333 
22 
1

**Process** (what I have come up with)

```
n  = input (“Enter a positive integer”)
r= 0
while r < n 
    c = (n – r) + 1
    while c > 0
        s = n – r
        print s 
        c = c – 1
    end
    r = r + 1
    n = n – 1
    print end l
end
```

**Problem:** I have used r for rows, and c for columns. The problem rises in c = (n – r) + 1 for first row. It makes the first row n+1, works for following rows. 
On dry run i get

**Input 3** 
**Pattern:**
444 
22 
1

Comment: i don't think the tags `c++` and `design-patterns` make sense here

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be **Input 5**?

Comment: Olydis, thanks for the input regarding tags. I'll be careful
Angew, input is variable, user enters input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
n = input (“Enter a positive integer”)
while n > 0 
    c = n
    while c > 0
        print n
        c = c – 1
    end
    n = n - 1
    print end l
end
```

Be careful about what meaning you give to your variables and therefore, how you treat them consitently ;)

Comment: Thanks! This makes it so simple and useful for following iterative problems.

Answer (score 2):

why are you using `while` for something that is an obviously an example of `for` statement?

```
n  = input (“Enter a positive integer”)

for(i=n ; i > 0 ; i--)
{
   for(j=0 ;j<i; j++)
   {
     print i;
   }

   print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah. To clarify, I started my first semester this month. taught in steps, we are supposed to solve given problems (and similar) with what we have learned so far as to practice and.. you get the pitch

Comment: @KazimHasan then let me just tell you you write your questions clearly and with a code part, keep up the good work and you'll graduate in no time