# I need to print a square using nested while loops . I think I have coded it with the right logic but it isn't giving me the desired output

Tags: c++

```
int number;
int column=0;
int row=0;

cout<<"Enter number :";

cin>>number;

while (row < number)       
{

    while(column < number)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        column=column+1;
    }

    cout<<endl;
    row=row+1;
}
```

Comment: what kind of output are we looking at here?

Comment: What is your desired output?  What are you actually getting?

Comment: Please specify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't resetting col to 0 each time.

Try this:

```
    int number;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    cout << "Enter number:  "
    cin >> number;
    while (row < number)
    {
        col = 0;
        while (col < number)
        {
            cout << "*";
            col++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        row++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    row++;
```

Comment: (I can't comment above, so I'm commenting on my own answer.)  He's getting, for an input of 3, "---" instead of "---\n---\n---".  (I had to use - instead of asterisk because SO thinks I'm trying to use italics or bold.)

Comment: Or use for-loops: http://ideone.com/lRU2HY

Answer (score 0):

Here is the loop:

```
while (row<number)
{ 
  while(column<number)
  {
    cout<<"*";
    column++;
  }
  column=0;
  cout<<endl;
  row=row+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rows = column we don't need to take a separate variable for rows 
**EDIT:** looks like we need to take a variable for rows after all as _gx pointed out subtracting from n itself decreases the no. of columns. Sorry for the rough mistake

```
n = input (“Enter a positive integer”)
r = n
while r > 0 
c = 0
while c < n
    print "*"
    c = c + 1
end
r = r - 1
print end l
```

end

Reference, [Write pseudocode of a program that prints such a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812543/write-pseudocode-of-a-program-that-prints-such-a-pattern)

Comment: A square is not a triangle: http://ideone.com/EzG2Ta

Comment: Ah. Yes, n-1 is the issue. Looks like we need to take a seperate variable for rows after all
n = r
and r = r - 1
Thanks for pointing out, will edit